# How to create a Stackbar using barplot for True/False Values in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am new to the world of R and I am currently trying to put a barplot together for a number of columns that I am comparing from 2 datasets. The following is an example of my first column, which is a unique id and I am checking to see if there is a match on 2 data sets:

```
    UID  UID_1
1 00125  00125
2 00128  00128
3     0  00190
4     0  00195
```

I then wrote the following code to match the 2 columns:

```
data1$MATCH <- data1$UID == data1$UID1
```

which gives me a 3rd column of TRUE/FALSE values.

```
    UID  UID_1  MATCH
1 00125  00125   TRUE
2 00128  00128   TRUE
3     0  00190  FALSE
4     0  00195  FALSE
```

Now if I create a new value of a count for my barplot:

```
counts <- table(data1$MATCH)
```

This gives me the following:

```
    Var1 Freq
1  FALSE    2
2   TRUE    2
```

which is what I want. The problem occurs when I add another column using the same process as above. My 2nd dataset, with the TRUE/FALSE values:

```
    AREA AREA_1 MATCH2
1     NY     NY   TRUE
2     UK     UK   TRUE
3     EU      0  FALSE
4     EU      0  FALSE
```

I then added this into my count code:

```
counts <- table(data1$MATCH, data2$MATCH2)
```

this then changes values into groups that I don't really want.

My Counts Table

```
    Var1   Var2 Freq
1  FALSE  FALSE    2
2   TRUE  FALSE    0
3  FALSE   TRUE    0
4   TRUE   TRUE    2
```

My Barplot code:

```
barplot(counts, main = "Matches",
        names.arg = c("Unique ID", "Area"), 
        xlab = "Number of Matches", 
        col = c("red", "darkgreen"),
        legend = rownames(counts))
```

What this does is group the true/false values against the columns whereas all I want is a stacked bar for my unique id (2 true / 2 false) and another bar for my area (2 true / 2 false).

I would really appreciate it if somebody could advise on where I have gone wrong and how I could fix this to achieve what I am trying to do.

What I am looking to find out is how i can build a barplot that shows 2 bars (unique id, area) and the split of true/false values for those attributes.

Currently my barplot splits the true/false values which don't necessarily belong to unique id and area.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, much appreciated.